# Increment letters by 2

Tags: php

I would like to increment a letter by 2. This way, A will become C, Z will become AB.

It works well when I increment by 1 with $letter++ but I can't find a way to do it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You can use this "print_r(range('a','z',2));"  https://eval.in/485464

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a function like this one to increment variable as many time as wished :

```
function increment($val, $increment = 2)
{
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $increment; $i++) {
        $val++;
    }

    return $val;
}
```

Usage :

```
$var = increment('a', 2);
var_dump($var);
```

Comment: Yes, but this does not include the transition from "Z" to "AA".

Comment: Yes it does ! Did you try it ?

Comment: Interesting. It did not seem obvious to me at first glance, but you are correct indeed. Sorry. Downvote retracted.

Comment: It works. And i didn't even thought about it... Too obvious maybe. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should use the functions [chr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php); and [ord()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php); to get the ASCII value and return it. Example code:

```
$letter = 'A';
//catch Y to add a letter + reset to A
if(strtoupper(substr($letter,-1)) == 'Y'{
    $letter = 'A'.substr($letter,0,strlen($letter)-1).'A';
}
//catch Z to add a letter + reset to B
else if(strtoupper(substr($letter,-1)) == 'Z'){
    $letter = 'A'.substr($letter,0,strlen($letter)-1).'B';
}
//nothing to catch here
else{
    $letter = substr($letter,0,strlen($letter)-1).(chr(ord(substr($letter,-1))+2));
}

// $letter = chr(ord($letter) + 2); //returns C
```

You should build in a function to make the jump from Z to AB and from Y to AA.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=A;$i<Z;$i++){                   

  echo ++$i." ";

}
```

Try this.